# Subtracting 1 hour from new Date and get strange result

Tags: angular, typescript

I am tring to get the current datetime minus 1 hour and I get an odd result.

## My Code

```js
    let myDate = new Date();
    let myStartDate = myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() -1);
```

I ran this at 10:15 today (18/08/2019) and I got `1566116120101` from `console.log(myStartDate);`

Not sure what that is, any ideas?

## My Goal

I want todays date and time minus 1 hour in the local time.

Comment: That's expected if you read the documentation of setHours(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Return_value. What else did you expect and why? If you want to print the updated date, then print myDate, not the value returned by setHours().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what was expected to be returned. As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Return_value):

Return value:

> The number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date.

```
let myDate = new Date();
let myStartDate = myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() -1);
console.log(myDate); // correct date
console.log(myStartDate); // correct date in milliseconds
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5s1dc6) example demonstrating that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your time subtracting, the value that you print is the timestamp of your date, that is the seconds ( or milliseconds ) passed after a time in 1970. If you want to parse it in a date format, you can:

```
let inDate = new Date(myStartDate)
console.log(inDate) // prints 2019-08-18T08:45:39.923Z
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not quite how `Date.setHours()` works. It doesn't return a modified date, but changes the original date and returns the timestamp.

So, in your case, you have the timestamp in `myStartDate`, and a modified date in `myDate`.

Note that this is not a safe way of setting an "hour earlier" date, as it might break on locales with summer time. Either use `Date.getUTCHours()` and `Date.setUTCHours()`, or *in my opinion* better yet, use timestamps:

```
let myDate = new Date();
let myStartDate = new Date(myDate - 60 * 60 * 1000);
```